# java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone please help me do the following in a java regular expression?

I need to read 3 characters from the 5th position from a given String ignoring whatever is found before and after.

Example : `testXXXtest`

Expected result : `XXX`

Comment: why regex? did you try substring

Answer (score 20):

<strike>You don't need regex at all.</strike>

<strike>Just use substring: `yourString.substring(4,7)`</strike>

Since you do need to use regex, you can do it like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".{4}(.{3}).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("testXXXtest");
matcher.matches();
String whatYouNeed = matcher.group(1);
```

What does it mean, step by step:

`.{4}` - any four characters

`(` - start capturing group, i.e. what you need

`.{3}` - any three characters

`)` - end capturing group, you got it now

`.*` followed by 0 or more arbitrary characters.

`matcher.group(1)` - get the 1st (only) capturing group.

Comment: because you have responded quickly may i ask u a question directly ? In this string "ABC Y C S       1 $  46C M 2/10                S    Y     FWPIV2". I need create a regex pattern to extract 2/20. All the fields before and space padded to make it fix length. for example ABC till Y is one word then Y C S ... properly space padded. i dont know i have explained it clearly..

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the [**substring()**](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/substring.html) method to accomplish this:

```
string example = "testXXXtest";
string result = example.substring(4,7);
```

Comment: thanks for that. But unfortunately this needs to be added on to an existing framework which uses regex.

Comment: @javaagn Such constraints should have been declared in the question.

Answer (score 3):

This might help: [Groups and capturing in java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg).

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "This is a testWithSomeDataInBetweentest.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("test([A-Za-z0-9]*)test");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("Matched: " + m.group(1));
    } else {
      System.out.println("No match.");
    }
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
Matched: WithSomeDataInBetween
```

If you don't want to match the entire pattern rather to the input string (rather than to seek a substring that would match), you can use `matches()` instead of `find()`. You can continue searching for more matching substrings with subsequent calls with `find()`.

Also, your question did not specify what are admissible characters and length of the string between two "test" strings. I assumed any length is OK including zero and that we seek a substring composed of small and capital letters as well as digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring for this, you don't need a regex.

```
yourString.substring(4,7);
```

I'm sure you could use a regex too, but why if you don't need it. Of course you should protect this code against null and strings that are too short.

Comment: A regEX pattern is what am looking for. I know it is easy in java as as you and some one else mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the String.replaceAll() Class Method**

If you don't need to be performance optimized, you can try the **String.replaceAll() class method** for a cleaner option:

```
String sDataLine = "testXXXtest";
String sWhatYouNeed = sDataLine.replaceAll( ".{4}(.{3}).*", "$1" );
```

References

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#using-regular-expressions-with-string-methods