# Regular expression for extracting values after a pattern

Tags: java, regex

How do i write a regular expression in Java which given a certain pattern, extracts the value after it and stores it in an array. If there is no value in after that pattern it should add a blank (i.e "") to the array.

As an example for pattern `&&`, I should get the following inputs and outputs:

```
  input=&&&&&&&&&&
  o/p=["","","",""];

  input=&&A&&123&&B&&985
  o/p=["A",123,B,985];
  input=&& && &&A&&488
  o/p=["","","A","488"]
```

Comment: take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405540/java-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

You can set the delimiter on a `Scanner` and then iterate through its values.

```
    public String[] getTokens() {   
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();         
        Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\&\\&");
        while(s.hasNext()) {
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        String[] a = new String[list.size()];
        return list.toArray(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `split`. You can omit the first result and use the rest from the output of the following code.

```
String testStr = "&&A&&123&&B&&985";
String[] splitString = testStr.split("(&&)");
for (String token : splitString) {
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

Comment: if there is nothing between&&&& i need a blank value

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String str = "&&A&&&&&&D&&123&&XX&&";
    String delimiters = "([&]{2})";

    // analyzing the string
    String[] tokensVal = str.split (delimiters);

    System.out.print ("[");
    for (String token: tokensVal) {
        // Print empty and space tokens
        if(token.isEmpty () || token.equals (" ")){
            System.out.print ("\"\",");
        } else {
            System.out.print (token + ",");
        }
    }
    System.out.print ("]");
}

O/P ["",A,"",D,]
```

There is one problem is here when there is only & in whole string eg "&&&&&&" then you have to handle it in special way.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that I don't know Java, but assuming it has the ability to replace and capture, you could do this in two steps.

First would be to replace any occurrence of

```
&&
```

with

```
&&\s
```

Second would be to iterate through the captured results returned from

```
&{2}([^&]+)
```

and trim the excess space off any results